# Wordpress Gravity Form Total

Tags: wordpress, nested-forms, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm trying to create a shop in **WordPress** using **Gravity Form**.

I have the main form for the products. This gravity form also includes 3 different nested forms for special deals.

Each nested form has his own different gravity form, each having his own total.

How can I make sure that the total of those nested forms will be included in the total of the main form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the Gravity Perks nested forms. If so the instructions for showing the total from nested forms in the parent form are here: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/#how-do-i-include-nested-entry-totals-in-the-parent-form-total